# What to put down under new carpet or "luxury vinyl tile" to prevent cold floors?

Tags: insulation, carpet, vinyl-flooring, draft

We have a hardwood living-dining room floor that was improperly installed (before we arrived), and squeaks and creaks something awful.  We plan to rip out the old flooring and put in LVT (luxury vinyl tile) that locks together and looks similar to hardwood.  ([Example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Pergo-XP-Royal-Oak-10-mm-Thick-x-7-1-2-in-Wide-x-47-1-4-in-Length-Laminate-Flooring-19-63-sq-ft-case-LF000890/301226255).)  We used something like this in our previous house and were very happy with the results.

The subfloor has a bulge in the middle.  We think that there is a structural beam there that used to have a dividing wall over it.  We suppose the house (built in the 1940's, upstate New York) settled around the edges, leaving the silly bulge in the middle of the floor where there wasn't any sinking.

My first question is, do we need to level the subflooring before laying the new flooring?  (I want to make sure we don't end up with a creaky floor again when we're all done.)  If so, with what method?  I have read about using roof shingles, and I've also heard about putting down little strips of different thicknesses and then putting down a new subflooring on top of that.

Second: the floor here is cold and frankly in some places feels rather drafty.  Would an underlayment (such as [TrafficMASTER
Premium 3-in-1 Underlayment](https://www.homedepot.com/p/TrafficMASTER-100-sq-ft-25-ft-x-4-ft-x-093-in-Premium-3-in-1-Underlayment-100779554/203956767)) help?  The friend who is going to help us install the flooring says he has always used a single thickness of newspaper instead of a commercial underlayment, and that has worked great for him (!).

Note that we have a semi-finished basement under the main floor of the house.  In principle we could put in some insulation batting in the "ceiling" of the basement, instead, if that's a better approach.

Alternatively, should we paint the subflooring with some sort of waterproofing?  Not that there's a water or moisture problem, but I wonder if that would be a good approach.  And/or caulk around the edges of the subflooring?

Lastly, how smooth does the subflooring need to be?  Obviously I don't know what it looks like yet -- but once it's exposed, what should we be checking for, e.g. nails sticking out, rough surfaces, dust and bigger particles, etc.?  Should we shop vac the whole thing?

Most of these same questions regarding the prep for the bedrooms, where we are going to put carpet (after pulling out the creaky hardwood flooring).  The floors in the bedrooms feel particularly cold and drafty.

Comment: You've asked a ton of questions and don't have any facts yet.  You'd be better off starting your project and asking questions as you go along. the questions would then be more informative and would yield better answers.

Comment: `subfloor has a bulge in the middle` ... this may be the reason for the creaky floor ... removing the hardwood may not resolve the problem

Comment: @jsotola - the noise is cause by two factors: the bulge is certainly part of it, but also the hardwood was installed without acclimating the wood first -- i.e., they put it in "green."

Comment: @JACK - I would prefer to plan things out.  Once I start installing the flooring, it will be too late to be leveling and underlaying, no?

Comment: None of that is going to help. You have to heat the floor or get better HVAC going. [in floor heat under laminate](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=in+floor+heat+under+laminate) – Google

Comment: @Mazura - I was wondering about that.  Are there certain types I should focus on, or certain types I should avoid? // I was also thinking about insulating the rim joists in the basement.

Comment: I've only done in-slab hydronics, and only seen heated floors in bathrooms. Insulating and dry-walling the basement ceiling would help, but the drafts aren't coming through the floor; it's lack of air sealing of the whole house. Maybe just add some vents in the basement and the floor won't be so freakishly cold upstairs.

Comment: @Mazura - "air sealing the whole house" - that's what I want to understand better.  While I have the floor up seems like it would be a good time to work on that.

Comment: Sorry got to vote to close for the reason what you put under the floor is really an opinion based issue. After that was tldr